# Telerik RadFilter - How to remove and expression from Radfilter programatically?

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I have a requirement where I need to remove an expression from RadFilter programatically.
My RadFilter is tied to a RadGrid and the user has an option to remove a column from the grid.

When the column is removed, I need to loop through all the expression in RadFilter and remove the ones that were defined on this column. Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out how to make this work. Telerik controls are black hole and there is not a whole lot of documentation out there if you want to implement something more complicated functionality and not just stick to the demo scenarios that they have. I hope this helps somebody.

```
public void YourMethod()
{
    //rfReport is RadFilter control defined somewhere on  your aspx page
    //fieldName is GridColumns's DataField property whose expression you want to
    //remove from RadFilter
    RemoveFilterExpressions(rfReport.RootGroup, string fieldName);
}

private void RemoveFilterExpressions(RadFilterGroupExpression filterGroupExpression, string fieldName)
{
    for (int i = filterGroupExpression.Expressions.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var exp = filterGroupExpression.Expressions[i];
        if (exp.FilterFunction == RadFilterFunction.Group)
        {
            RemoveFilterExpressions(exp as RadFilterGroupExpression, fieldName);
            //Remove the filterGroupExpression if it has No expressions
            if (((RadFilterGroupExpression)exp).Expressions.Count == 0)
            {
                filterGroupExpression.Expressions.Remove(exp);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (((RadFilterNonGroupExpression)exp).FieldName == fieldName)
            { 
                //Remove expression if FieldName == fieldName
                filterGroupExpression.Expressions.Remove(exp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```